# Running jrxlm report with Jasper Server

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have created jrxml report by iReport. Then I have run it with JasperServer and it work perfectly. I have generate pdf report by this URL:

```
http://localhost:8081/jasperserver/flow.html/flowFile/my_report.pdf
```

It works well but when I tried to refresh the page I get this error:

```
An id is required to lookup a FlowDefinition
```

Also when I try to call this REST service in JasperServer client application I get this error:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: Client response status: 500
```

This is the Java client application to call the REST service:

```
public final static String serverUrl = "http://localhost:8081/jasperserver/flow.html/flowFile/my_report.xls";
public final static String serverUser = "jasperadmin";
public final static String serverPassword = "jasperadmin";

static File outPutDir= new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Report report = new Report();
        report.setUrl("/reports/samples/Employees");
        report.setOutputFolder(outPutDir.getAbsolutePath());
        JasperserverRestClient client = JasperserverRestClient.getInstance(serverUrl, serverUser, serverPassword);
        File reportFile  = client.getReportAsFile(report);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: `I get this error com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: Client response status: 500` - Did you check log files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**flowId**

When calling `flow.html` you must provide an action, which is put into the `flowId`. JasperServer is using the `flow.html` to provide an interface which can be accessed over the URL. For example if calling a report this would be:

```
_flowId=viewReportFlow
```

Also the report and parameters have to be provided. So with this in mind the URL could look like this:

```
http://localhost:8081/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&reportUnit=/reports/samples/Employees&j_username=the_user&j_password=secret&output=pdf
```

**Server error**

When connecting to the server, this URL is used

```
http://localhost:8081/jasperserver/flow.html/flowFile/my_report.xls
```

This is *not* the server URL used by `JasperserverRestClient`. The server URL should look like this:

```
http://localhost:8081/jasperserver
```

*NOTE:* `flow.html` is for accessing JasperServer without logging into the UI. It is *not* an application path where you should put your reports.

Comment: Thanks tobi6 ,you helped me.

Comment: Can you help me how get path of report for rest client ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37509433/jasperserver-rest-client-path

Comment: Happy to help. Please consider accepting my answer (or another) if it worked for you ([How to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)).